# Convert DateTime to MM/dd/yyyy in c#

Tags: c#, date, datetime

I am calling the webservice which gives me the Datetime as "dd-MM-yyyy 00:00:00". Now i want to save it to the database. So in order to save the date, i have to convert the date format to MM/dd/yyyy. I have tried below code to convert the date time format, but nothing works for me

```
1. DateTime.ParseExact(string, "MM/dd/yyyy", culture);
2. Convert.ToDateTime(string).ToString("MM/dd/yyyy",CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Can anyone help me on this?

Comment: "So in order to save the date, i have to convert the date format to MM/dd/yyyy." Really? I would expect you to be able to just pass in a `DateTime`. That's definitely better than converting it back to a string. What kind of database are you using, and how are you inserting it?

Comment: You don't need to convert anything. A date is a date. You store it in a DateTime column without any kind of conversion

Comment: Per René Vogt's answer, if you don't tell us what kind of database system and connection you're using we have no way of knowing what your problem is. Formatting a DateTime to a string and storing a DateTime in the database are two different things.

Answer (score 13):

DateTime type have not any specific format you can directly save it to database. But if you want it as specific format string then you can do it by

```
//input date string as dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss format
string date = "17-10-2016 20:00:00";
//dt will be DateTime type
DateTime dt = DateTime.ParseExact(date, "dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
//s will be MM/dd/yyyy format string
string s = dt.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy");
```

and if you get input `date` as `DateTime` type then you can get formatted string directly

```
string s1 = date.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy");
```

Answer (score 5):

The `DateTime` is a struct that does not have *any* information about something like a "format".

You only use a format if you want to create a string representation of the `DateTime`'s value. What you mean by "nothing works for me" is probably that your debugger always uses the same format to display the value of your `DateTime`.

What you have to do to insert the value into your database depends on the database system and the kind of connection you use. Normally you should use a parameterized query where you can pass the `DateTime` as it is and everything will work fine.

If you have to put your `DateTime` value directly into your query string, you can simply use `myDate.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy",CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);`. But I am absolutely sure you use a database connection that supports parameterized queries accepting your `DateTime` directly and I would not suggest to convert the value back into a string representation.

Answer (score 2):

```
var dateTime = "28-08-1993 12:12:12";
DateTime dt = DateTime.ParseExact(dateTime, "dd-MM-yyyy hh:mm:ss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
var convertedDate = dt.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy");
Console.WriteLine(convertedDate);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
DateTime date=DateTime.Now;

string result =  date.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy");
```

Answer (score 0):

You Can also do it by capturing day/month/year separately....

```
string formattedDate= Convert.ToDateTime(your_date_object).Day.ToString() + "/" + Convert.ToDateTime(your_date_object).Month.ToString() + "/" + Convert.ToDateTime(your_date_object).Year.ToString();
```